# Rollback using repo command?

Tags: android, git, repository

How can I do a rollback when I use the [repo command](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html)?

I made some changes in some files and now I want to rollback to the source that was downloaded when I used the `repo sync` command.

I haven't committed the changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right commands is:

If you want to revert changes made to your working copy, do this:
`repo forall -c "git checkout ."`

If you want to revert changes made to the index (i.e., that you have added), do this:
`repo forall -c "git reset"`

If you want to revert a change that you have committed, do this:
`repo forall -c "git revert ..."`

Answer (score 1):

Use `git reset` then.

> Repo is not meant to replace Git, only to make it easier to work with Git in the context of Android. [via](http://source.android.com/source/version-control.html)

According to the [Repo command reference](http://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html) there is no equivalent of `git reset` command (yet?)